# Flow: Fast Lookup with date filter

Tags: lookup, visual-workflow

I'm in a flow and I Fast Created a bunch of opportunities. Now I need the record IDs of those opportunities. Since they are not automatically added to the SObject Collection I wanted to do a Fast Lookup of opportunities. I really wanted to do a filter such that:

> Created Date = {!$Flow.CurrentDate}

But this causes the Lookup to come back empty. Is there something else I can do to get this lookup criteria to work? Or to get the Record IDs for a collection I just created?

Comment: A workaround I'm going to try is to populate with all of the Opportunities for the contact, and then using a loop and a decision element using the above formula to see if I can sort through them this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDs actually are all there. The problem is that I assume you are doing this in the same Flow so there has been no commit to the database yet, thus no CreatedDate. But you can access the Ids, so I don't know why you'd need the filter at all. If you use the Collection variables again you will have access to the variables.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=vpm_designer_elements_fast_create.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks. I realize now that an issue I had before was not what I thought it was, which had further reaching effects than I initially thought.